# Stop Org Mode from exporting headline tags

Tags: pdf, emacs, org-mode

When I setup a headline like the following

```
#+SELECT_TAGS: export
...snip...
* A Heading :export:
```

and do PDF export, the `:export:` text shows up in the heading.

How do I suppress this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer on the [Emacs (beta) SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/remove-org-mode-tags-from-ascii-but-not-latex-export)

Put `tags:nil` into the options line, i.e. something like:

```
 #+OPTIONS: tags:nil
```

(along with any other options)